# Sum of independent r.v. converge in distribution to Poisson(1)

Tags: probability, limits, proof-verification, poisson-distribution

> Let $X_{n1}, X_{n2}, . . . , X_{nn}$ be independent random variables with a common distribution given as follows:
>   $P(X_{nk} = 0) = 1 − 1/n-1/n^2$ , $P(X_{nk} = 1) = 1/n$, $P(X_{nk} = 2) = 1/n^2$ ,
>   where $k = 1, 2, . . . , n$ and n = $2, 3, . . . .$
>
> Set $S_n = X_{n1} +X_{n2} +· · ·+X_{nn}$,
>   $n ≥ 2$. Show that $S_n → \textrm{Poisson}(1)$ as $n → ∞$ in distribution.

I decided to check by characteristic functions convergence:
Let $Y\sim \textrm{Poisson}(1)$

$E(e^{itY})=e^{(e^{it}-1)}.$

$E(e^{itS_n})=E(e^{it(X_{n1}+X_{n2}+...+X_{nn})})$, here are $n$ independent elements, so $E(e^{itS_n})=[E(e^{itX_{n1}})]^n$

$E(e^{itX_{n1}}) = e^{it0}0+e^{it}(1/n)+e^{2it}(1/n^2)=\frac{e^{it}}{n}(1+\frac{e^{it}}{n})$

as $n→∞$  $[\frac{e^{it}}{n}(1+\frac{e^{it}}{n})]^n→0$.

Which is wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: I don't see a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your computation of $Ee^{itX_{n1}}$ you have taken $P\{X_{nk}=0\}$ as $0$ instead of $1-1/n-1/n^{2}$.

Comment: Yeah... ( Thanks! I will recompute it.

Comment: Ok, now when I change it $E(e^{itX_{n1}})=1-1/n-1/n^2+e^{it}(1/n)+e^{2it}(1/n2)=1-1/n(1-1/n)+e^{it}/n(1+e^{it}/n)$ and in limit this goes to $1$, which is not $e^{(e^{it}-1)}$ too.

Comment: For any $t$,
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{it S_n}]
= \left(1-\frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{e^{it}}{n} + \frac{e^{2 it}}{n^2}\right)^n 
= \left(1+\frac{e^{it}-1}{n} + o(1/n)\right)^n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e^{e^{it}-1}.$$